# Perturbations of a Fredholm operator by a positive function

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, operator-theory

The unbounded operator $\frac{d}{dx}+x$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$ is Fredholm with index $1$, for example by the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3476994/image-and-invertibility-of-fracddx-x-on-mathbbr).

I'm wondering whether we can replace the function $x$ with other functions with suitable growth behavior and still retain Fredholmness of the operator. More precisely:

**Question 1:** Let $f$ be a smooth odd function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$f(x)\geq x$$
for all $x\in [0,\infty)$. Is the operator $\frac{d}{dx}+f$ Fredholm?

*Edit:* As indicated in the comments, the answer to this question is yes, by essentially the same argument as in the case of $\frac{d}{dx}+x$. Thus let us consider a variation of this question in a more general setting.

**Question 2:** Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $T$ be a Fredholm operator on $L^2(M)$. Let $f$ be a smooth non-negative function on $M$. Then is the operator $T+f$ Fredholm?

Comment: What happened when you tried to emulate the linked question and tried to find an appropriate $e^{g(x)}$ to make this operator conjugate to ordinary differentiation?

Comment: I see, the analogous thing works. Thanks!

Comment: The answer to question (2) is trivially no, for one could take $T=-I$, and $f=1$.

Comment: @Ruy Indeed...this attempt was a bit too general. Still, I wonder if there is a condition  that allows one to add functions to Fredholm differential operators and retain Fredholmness.